# Set calendar timezone in angular-bootstrap-calendar?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) to display the calendar of an short term rental listing.  Currently, the calendar displays the dates in the timezone of the browser but the user isn't always in the same timezone as the listing they are managing.

How can I set the calendar's timezone so that it shows the dates in the timezone of the listing and not the timezone of the bowser?

Comment: This plugin uses `moment.js` as a dependency right? Why don't you use moment.js to [set the timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/)?

Comment: It can use moment.js as a dependency but the timezone stuff is ignored.  Here's a link about it: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues/544#issuecomment-284156221

Comment: Are you storing the UTC value for the listings in your backend? Then you could manually change the locale of the calendar.

Comment: @yoonjesung I'm storing them in the same timezone as the listing but I could easily convert them to utc.  I'm just not sure how to take the browser's timezone and re-convert the time to match.  It's really confusing and I'm not sure I can wrap my head around it.  Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @yoonjesung post something in the next 5 hours and I'll give you the bounty . :)